# Finding the first tag applied to a SHA1

Tags: git

I have a requirement where a repo gets tagged after every successful build. Now I want to write a script to get the build it was integrated to by giving the bug number.

I get the SHA corresponding to the bug from the below command.

*git log  --pretty=oneline | grep  | awk '{print $1}'*

Now if I run a **git tag --contains SHA1** with SHA1 from the above command it has a number of tags, how do I figure out which build the change went into?

I am thinking of sorting the commits by date and getting the tag from the date the SHA1 was committed. Is there a better way to get this info?

To put it simply, 
How do you get the first tag applied to a SHA1?

Comment: Don't your build tags follow a simple scheme which allows to select the earlier one?

Comment: Perhaps you want `git tag --points-at`?  (This works only if every such commit has a tag, i.e., you're not willing to take `v311.17alpha` which points to a commit that is just a few commits away from the target commit, but not actually pointing *directly* to that commit.)